# AWS IAM policy to limit access to CodeCommit branches with wildcards in their names

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

Amazon now support being able to limit access to CodeCommit repository on a branch by branch basis by means of IAM policies.
I have successfully denied access to specific branches using a form of the policy below, but cannot find a way to deny access to all branches beginning with a certain name. 
Ie: master and develop are specific branches but then I have release-1, release-2 etc which I also want to deny. 
What I want is to be able to use a wildcard. I've tried release-* but that didn't work.
Is their a format to include wildcards in the  "codecommit:References"?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:GitPush",
                "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
                "codecommit:PutFile",
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:80398EXAMPLE:MyDemoRepo",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "codecommit:References": [
                        "refs/heads/master",
                        "refs/heads/develop",
                        "refs/heads/release-[now what]"
                    ]
                },
            "Null": {
                "codecommit:References": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an IAM policy, which is supposed to support all the conditional operators listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html .  But since `GitPush` action itself involves two separate actions behind the scene, to achieve the expected behavior, the ..IfExists conditional operator family should be used.  That being said, in order to use wildcard in this case, `StringLikeIfExists` should be used. Your policy could be like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:GitPush"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:80398EXAMPLE:MyDemoRepo",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "codecommit:References": [
                        "refs/heads/release-*"
                    ]
                },
            "Null": {
                "codecommit:References": false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:GitPush",
                "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
                "codecommit:PutFile",
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:80398EXAMPLE:MyDemoRepo",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "codecommit:References": [
                        "refs/heads/master",
                        "refs/heads/prod"
                    ]
                },
            "Null": {
                "codecommit:References": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This way both the wildcard matching and exact matching should be supported.

Comment: Works a charm thanks. StringLikeIfExists was the key to it.